# What is the scope of a statically declared struct in c++

Tags: c++

So it's been a while since I did anything with c++ so please help me out on this issue.

I have a struct that I declare in a scope and then put in a map. How come this instance is still there outside of the scope. Shouldn't the allocated instance be deallocated?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

struct foo {
  int key;
  int val;
};

int main() {
  std::map<int,foo> map;
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    foo f; // allocated 1 time only?
    f.key = 1000 + i;
    if (i%2==0) {
      f.val = i;
    }
    map.insert(std::make_pair(i, f)); // f is copied into the pair?
  }

  for (std::map<int, foo>::iterator it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it->first;
    std::cout << " :: ";
    std::cout << it->second.key;
    std::cout << " -> ";
    std::cout << it->second.val;
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

this will generate the following

```
0 :: 1000 -> 0
1 :: 1001 -> 0
2 :: 1002 -> 2
3 :: 1003 -> 2
4 :: 1004 -> 4
5 :: 1005 -> 4
6 :: 1006 -> 6
7 :: 1007 -> 6
8 :: 1008 -> 8
9 :: 1009 -> 8
```

Is the comments in the code correct?

Now, say I would like to only instanciate val every other time, and the even times i would like it to be 0 (default). What would be the safest and most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: containers store copies of the elements you insert, or ... well not really clear what struct you mean that goes out of scope. What instance do you mean?

Comment: Standard containers store **copies** of the objects you insert (unless you explicitly make them store pointers or `reference_wrapper`s).

Comment: Am I misunderstanding or are you really wondering why the values you put in a map are still there?

Comment: btw please provide a [mcve].  This code wont compile

Comment: if what you are doing would not work, how would you insert an element into a container in general?

Comment: offtopic: if the keys are merely continuous indices you probably should rather use a `std::vector`

Comment: The instance in the map is a different instance. I think you need to unlearn some Java.

Comment: @molbdnilo in java the instance would also be kept alive as long as the map holds a reference

Comment: What did you *expect* this code to do, and how is that expectation different from what *actually* happens?

Comment: @user463035818 In Java, there would be one instance, but there are several with different lifetimes here.

Comment: @molbdnilo somehow a bit strange that "several with different lifetimes" is what I consider as natural and easy while "one instance" is confusing me whenever i try to wrap my head around it ;)

Comment: sorry about the missunderstandings (and non-compilation). I'm on a train and was trying to rewrite (the relevant parts of my) my code here without trying it out. I will make a better example when I get get actual code. Thanks for your thoughts though.

Comment: The code will not compile as there is no `main` entry point.

Answer (score 1):

Containers hold copies of the values, and these copies
will have the same lifetime as the container. This is
called 'value-semantics', and is a key component of C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct SomeType {
    int val;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    {
        int a = 3;
        int b = a;
        a = 4;
        cout << b << endl; // this prints 3, int is a value type
    }

    {
        SomeType a = {3};
        SomeType b = a;
        a.val = 4;
        cout << b.val << endl; // this prints 3, SomeType is a value type
    }

    {
        vector<int> a = {3};
        vector<int> b = a;
        a[0] = 4;
        cout << b[0] << endl; // this prints 3, vector is a value type
    }
}
```

As you can see, C++ follows value-semantics (almost) everywhere.
The only exceptions are thing like `std::shared_ptr`, which are
*designed* to use reference/pointer semantics instead.

In general, when designing types in C++, do what `int`s do.

Regarding your updated question, `foo` is default-constructed 10 times
(in the for loops body), copy constructed ten times (while creating pairs),
lastly move-constructed ten times (while inserted into the container).

Your code fails to initialize `foo::val` half of the time.

When I compile it on https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/
I get:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':   main.cpp:18:35: error:
'f.foo::val' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
     map.insert(std::make_pair(i, f)); // f is copied into the pair?
```

(compiled with std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic)

Failing to initialize a variable, and still reading it is UB
(Undefined Behavior), so anything can happen;

To get the output you requested, and fewer copies, try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct foo {
    int key;
    int val;
};

int main() {
    std::map<int,foo> map;
    int val = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        int key = 1000 + i;
        if (i%2==0)
            val = i; // not doubled
        map.emplace(i, foo{key, val});
    }

    for (auto&& item : map) {
        std::cout << item.first << " :: " << item.second.key;
        std::cout << " -> " << item.second.val << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange. When I try It out on http://cpp.sh/ it doesn't complain and outputs what I wrote.
What makes me confused is the val output. 0,0,2,2,4,4,6,6,8,8. This will suggest that it sets val every other time and don't set it the other times. But since it gets the value of the last iterations assignment I wonder if the foo f declaration only generates one allocation.

Comment: I use -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic. Also, without that, the values should be 0,0,4,4,8,8, etc. its because the new `foo` is allocated in the same space as the last, and this is thus UB

Comment: however the case, it seems like a lot of copying is beeing done here. 20 or 30 times? All I want is 10 objects. How would I do that?

Comment: Ah yes, That might be the case that foo f is allocated 10 times in the same space and thus get the previous iteration value.